# Empty fields are being sent to database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Hibernate .
I have a dao :

```
public interface DmRequestDao extends DaoSupport<DmRequestDomain>
```

where

```
 DmRequestDomain extends JodaIdTrackableBaseEntity<DmRequestDomain>
```

and is annotated with @Entity.

This contains all the column names for the table it represents.

Then my service class has the above dao object autowired.
I can see the values of the DmRequestDomain being correctly printed in the log file.

But when I call an add over this dao, I see in my server logs that all the empty values are being sent.

```
dmpRequestDao.add(object of DmRequestDomain);
```

What could be the probable cause here.

The query I see in server logs is

```
insert
into
    DM_REQUEST
    (CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_DATE, version, DISCONNECT_REASON, DISCONNECT_REASON_CODE,  id)
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,)>
```

Comment: Are you sure that those "?"'s are not just placeholders? You might have to enable printing the actual values to the log

Comment: Yeah, that's enabled. I can see values for other tables

Comment: Can you post some more code? Maybe the actual construction of the domain object

Answer (score 0):

Using all Columns in Insert/Update-Statements is Hibernates/JPAs default behaviour.

You could change that by annotating the @Entity with [@DynamicInsert](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicInsert.html) and/or [@DynamicUpdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html).

However, be aware that those are non standard (non JPA) Annotations and the performance-impact may even be negative ...

Comment: Can't take a risk of having a performance impact. Its an enterprise app.